# Nested SQL queries in Django

Tags: django, django-queryset

I've got a working SQL query that I'm trying to write in Django (without resorting to RAW) and was hoping you might be able to help.

Broadly, I'm looking to next two queries - the first calculates a COUNT, and then I'm looking to calculate an AVERAGE of the COUNTS.  (this'll give you the average number of items on a ticket, per location)

The SQL that works is:

```
SELECT location_name, Avg(subq.num_tickets) FROM (
    SELECT Count(ticketitem.id) AS num_tickets, location.name AS location_name 
    FROM ticketitem 
        JOIN ticket ON ticket.id = ticketitem.ticket_id
        JOIN location ON location.id = ticket.location_id
        JOIN location ON location.id = location.app_location_id
    GROUP BY ticket_id, location.name) AS subq
GROUP BY subq.location_name;
```

For my Django code, I'm trying something like this:

```
    # Get the first count
    qs = TicketItem.objects.filter(<my complicated filter>).\                 
    values('ticket__location__app_location__name','posticket').\
                                annotate(num_tickets=Count('id'))  
    # now get the average of the count
    qs2 = qs.values('ticket__location__app_location__name').\
    annotate(Avg('num_tickets')).\
    order_by('location__app_location__name')
```

but that fails because num_tickets doesn't exist ... Anyway - suspect I'm being slow. Would love someone to enlighten me!

Answer (score 0):

Check out the section on aggregating annotations from the [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/aggregation/#aggregating-annotations).  Their example takes an average of a count.

Comment: Hi there - thanks for your help.I tried that example but it uses "annotate" and then "aggregate", which gives me one aggregated result i..e that would give me an average overall, but I in fact want an average by location --- I assumed to do that I need a values/annotate combo (essentially a GROUP BY).

Answer (score 0):

I was playing around with this a bit in a manage.py shell, and I think the django ORM might not be able to do that kind of annotation. Honestly you're probably going to have to resort to doing a raw query or bind in something like https://github.com/Deepwalker/aldjemy which would let you do that via SQLAlchemy.

When I playing with this I tried

```
(my_model.objects.filter(...)
    .values('parent_id', 'parent__name', 'thing')
    .annotate(Count('thing'))
    .values('name', 'thing__count')
    .annotate(Avg('thing__count')))
```

Which gave a lovely traceback about `FieldError: Cannot compute Avg('thing__count'): 'thing__count' is an aggregate`, which makes sense since I doubt the ORM is trying to convert that first group by to a nested query.